# Building an object by looping thru two arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, multidimensional-array

Pretty straightforward.

I need to construct a function `objOfMatches` that accepts two arrays and a callback. objOfMatches will build an object and return it. To build the object, `objOfMatches` will test each element of the first array using the callback to see if the output matches the corresponding element (by index) of the second array. If there is a match, the element from the first array becomes a key in an object, and the element from the second array becomes the corresponding value.

```
function objOfMatches(array1, array2, callback) {
    //create obj
    var obj = {}

    //loop thru first array
    for(let i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < array2.length; j++) {
            if (callback(array1[i]) === array2[j]) {                
                obj.array1[i] = array2[j];
            }
        }
    }
    return obj;
}

console.log(objOfMatches(['hi', 'howdy', 'bye', 'later', 'hello'], ['HI', 'Howdy', 'BYE', 'LATER', 'hello'], function(str) { return str.toUpperCase(); }));
// should log: { hi: 'HI', bye: 'BYE', later: 'LATER' }
```

Looks quite simple, yet I'm not fully understanding why does it throw a TypeError in the console. `(TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined)`

Can someone explain what's going on?

Comment: Try `obj[array1[i]] = array2[j];`.

Comment: @OriDrori uhm, this works. Sounds weird, but `obj.array1[i] = array2[j]`; doesn't look like a syntax error. I was clearly wrong.

Comment: It's not, but the meaning is not what you think. `obj.array1[i]  = array2[j]` ->set index i of the obj property array to a value, and not set the key by the name of text that is in index i in the array.

Comment: it's called a bracket notation. You can use it either to access or set a property of an object.

Comment: Why is `'hello' ` not part of your expected result?

Comment: And why is `howdy` also not in it? This is anything but *pretty straightforward*.

Comment: @connexo see the callback that's being passed into objOfMatches.

Comment: It always helps wrapping long lines ;)... Adjusted my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match *corresponding* elements you don't need to loop through both arrays. You can loop through one and use the index to find the corresponding object in the other.

[`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) is nice for this because it will let you build your return object in place and it provides the index of the current loop iteration. You just run the test and assign the key/value if the test is true.

```js
function objOfMatches(arr1, arr2, callback){
  return arr1.reduce((obj, current, index) => {
    if(arr2[index] === callback(current)) obj[current] = arr2[index]
    return obj
  }, {})
}

console.log(objOfMatches(['hi', 'howdy', 'bye', 'later', 'hello'], ['HI', 'Howdy', 'BYE', 'LATER', 'hello'], function(str) { return str.toUpperCase(); }));
```

Comment: nicely put Mark.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming both arrays are of equal lengths and the indexes of matching elements match, a very straightforward reduce gets you there:

```js
const x = ['hi', 'howdy', 'bye', 'later', 'hello'],
      y = ['HI', 'Howdy', 'BYE', 'LATER', 'hello'];

console.log(x.reduce((a,v,i)=>Object.assign(a,{[v]:y[i]}),{}))
```

If you need to check for the match existence and position, this is what you'd  need to modify to make `Array.prototype.reduce` work for you:

```js
const x = ['hi', 'later', 'howdy', 'bye', 'hello', 'foo'],
      y = ['HI', 'baz', 'Howdy', 'BYE', 'LATER', 'hello', 'bar'];

console.log(x.reduce((a,v)=> {
    let i = y.indexOf(v.toUpperCase())
    return i === -1 ? a : Object.assign(a, {[v]:y[i]})
  },{}
))
```

Answer (score 0):

Following your approach, you should use this `obj[array1[j]] = array2[i]`, here the example:

```js
function objOfMatches(array1, array2, callback) {
    //create obj
    var obj = {}

    //loop thru first array
    for(let i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < array2.length; j++) {
            if (callback(array1[i]) === array2[j]) {   
                if(!array1[j] in obj) obj[array1[j]]  = [] 
                obj[array1[j]] = array2[i];
            }
        }
    }
    return obj;
}

console.log(objOfMatches(['hi', 'howdy', 'bye', 'later', 'hello'], ['HI', 'Howdy', 'BYE', 'LATER', 'hello'], function(str) { return str.toUpperCase(); }));
```

Comment: Hi Emeeus, this solution is pretty instructive. Could you please expain the nested if statement a bit more?  Particularly, this section: if(!array1[j] in obj) obj[array1[j]]  = []  obj[array1[j]] = array2[i];. Thank you